Does sending value to fucntion uses less memory than doing otherwise?
I was doing leetcode and when i send value to a function (example: function(x)) it uses less memory and gives shorter runtime than doing otherwise (example: function()). Is that supposed to be like that?
This code uses more memory and has longer runtime:
var createCounter = function(init) {
    let value = init;
    const firstValue = init;
    return {
        increment(){
            ++value;
            return value;
        },
        decrement(){
            --value;
            return value;
        },
        reset(){
            value = firstValue;
            return value;
        }
    }
};

This code uses less memory and has shorter runtime:
var createCounter = function(init) {
    let value = init;
    const firstValue = init;
    return {
        increment(init){
            ++value;
            return value;
        },
        decrement(init){
            --value;
            return value;
        },
        reset(init){
            value = firstValue;
            return value;
        }
    }
};

I don't really understand why.

I cannot believe that adding an unusused parameter to a function makes it run faster. What exactly are you basing this on - do you have any performance metrics?

There's no difference, leetcode's runtime always different depending on its load. Don't trust leetcode's benchmark, it's useless to some degree.
` Chrome/125
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>            n=100       |     n=1000      |      n=10000      |     n=100000    
param     1.00x x10m 408 | ■ 1.00x x1m 339 |   1.02x x100k 335 | ■ 1.00x x10k 328
pure    ■ 1.00x x10m 406 |   1.01x x1m 343 | ■ 1.00x x100k 330 |   1.01x x10k 331
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


let $length = 100;

var createCounter = function(init) {
    let value = init;
    const firstValue = init;
    return {
        increment(){
            ++value;
            return value;
        },
    }
};

var createCounter = function(init) {
    let value = init;
    const firstValue = init;
    return {
        increment(init){
            ++value;
            return value;
        },
    }
};

// @benchmark pure
const counter = createCounter();
let i = $length;
while(i--) counter.increment;

// @benchmark param
{
const counter = createCounter();
let i = $length;
while(i--) counter.increment;
}

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



